# What is the difference between boolean and bool in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am learning MySQL and when I wanted to add a boolean column, I saw there were two options: bool and boolean. Is there any difference between them? Thank you for your time.

Edit: what should I write in the length of the bool type.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

BOOL and BOOLEAN are both synonyms from TINYINT(1) ([source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html)). In other words, there is no difference.

Comment: then why are there both?

Comment: @devman Personal preference, legacy reasons, who knows. SQL is not particular about types. There's other things like INT and INTEGER, DEC and DECIMAL. There's no meaning to the difference and which one you used is probably not even recorded by the database.